# How to fix end slash "/" problem in MVC Attribute routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, attributerouting

I have a fixed link for my project like

Link: domain/controller/firstname-lastname/

Where Url_name ='firstname-lastname' is a parameter, that's why I had to use attribute routing to hide the action from the URL.

The list is coming from page 1 and there is a list of links for different user Like

```
<a class="artist" id=' + data.Id + ' href="Contr/' + data.Url_name + '">' NAME </a>
```

1.domain/controller/firstname1-lastname/

2.domain/controller/firstname2-lastname/

.....

Then when the user clicks on the link system will go to the second page (page 2) with the Url_name only.

```
[Route("Contr/{name}")]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

At this point when the view will load them in the Javascript, I tried to take the name from the URL like

```
var url = document.URL;
var lastChar = url[url.length - 1];
var name;
var splittedStr = url.split('/');
if (lastChar !== "/") 
{       
    name = splittedStr[splittedStr.length - 1];
} 
else 
{       
    name = splittedStr[splittedStr.length - 2];
}
```

Then I am calling another action through ajax(Script side) to get the data to display.

```
var url = "GetData/" + name + "/" + artistId + "/" + direction + "";
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',

        // data: { artistId: artistId, 'direction': 'none' },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function (data) {
            $("#hidId").val(data.Id);
            $("#aName").html(data.Vorname + " " + data.Name);
            //and so on.
        }
});
```

The corresponding Action in the controller is

```
[Route("Contr/GetData/{name?}/{aId:int?}/{direction?}")]       
public ActionResult GetData(string name,int? aId, string direction)
{ 
    //searcing code for coming paraeter
}
```

My problem is, in the link if there is no slash ("/") at the tail then everything is working correctly. But if there is then the call is concatenating with the present url like

> domain/controller/firstname1-lastname/GetData/name/0/none

And it's not calling the GetData action in the controller.
Could anyone help in this situation ??

Comment: What is the actual URL, and what is the expected URL?

Comment: domain/controller/firstname1-lastname/ .........  this is the URL when people click. Then at the loading page, there is function GetData(string name,int? Id, string direction) . the name parameter is coming from the URL. but if there is a tailing slash the this function is going 

domain/controller/firstname1-lastname/GetData/name/0/none

causes the problem

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Thats the link is working without slash("/")
https://www.kuenstlerverzeichnis-koeln.de/Kuenstler/Walter-Asmuth

If I configured with https://www.kuenstlerverzeichnis-koeln.de/Kuenstler/Walter-Asmuth/ 
then its not working and the link generated is 
https://www.kuenstlerverzeichnis-koeln.de/Kuenstler/Walter-Asmuth/GetKuenstlerGalleryData/Walter-Asmuth/0/none

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its the right way or not but I have solved the problem by resetting the URL without a slash("/")>

```
window.location = url.substr(0, url.length-1);
```

as far as I learn if there is a slash("/") then it waiting for the next string to append for the attribute routing.
that was the problem!!!